# Calling a method that includes a List of an object as Parameter

Tags: c#

I have a method that looks like following:

```
method(List<Car> list)
{

}
```

How do i call a method in main that has a list of Car as parameter?

Comment: Instantiate the class which contains the method if it is an instance method, and call it on that instantiation. E.G MyClass instance = new MyClass(); instance.method(carList);

Comment: So to set you on the right track early. You method if it doesn't need list specific method calls should take cars in as IEnumerable<Car> cars. This way you can pass in arrays, lists or anything else that inherits IEnumerable and you are not type specific to List<T>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by.... creating a list of cars, adding the cars you are interested in, and calling it?

```
var list = new List<Car>();
list.Add(new Car { Color = "Blue" });
list.Add(new Car { Color = "Green" });
method(list);
```

The bigger issue, perhaps, is "how do I call a non-static method from a static method such as `Main()`", to which there are two possible answers:

- make the method `static` (if it doesn't need instance state)
- create an instance of the declaring type

Assuming we mean the latter:

```
var obj = new SomeType(); // assuming an accessible parameterless ctor exists
obj.method(list);
```

Comment: and where does color come from?

Comment: @user it was simply an example of initializing the different cars that were in the list; I'm assuming your `Car` type has some *actual* properties - use those instead. `Color` was simply something indicative - I'm pretty sure most people would agree that cars often have a color.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not working?

```
var cars = new List<Car>(); //Get your list of cars
method(cars);
```